# Why doesn’t RegEx pattern \b(\w*->ShowMessage())\b in Notepad++ capture the initial “$” in $com_auditdetails_list->ShowMessage()?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to change variation of `$com_auditdetails_list->ShowMessage()`methods to a global `ShowMessage()` function.
My search RegEx pattern `\b(\w*->ShowMessage())\b` in Notepad++ finds `com_auditdetails_list->ShowMessage()` excluding the initial “$”.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this pattern include the "$"?

Here are some of the variations:

```
E:\www\erequestubn\fullpath\atm_requestsdownloadlist.php (1 hit)
Line 233: <?php `$atm_requests_list->ShowMessage()` ?>
E:\www\erequestubn\fullpath\atm_requestsdownloadsrch.php (1 hit)
Line 132: <?php `$atm_requests_search->ShowMessage()` ?>
E:\www\erequestubn\fullpath\atm_requestslist.php (1 hit)
Line 202: <?php `$atm_requests_list->ShowMessage()` ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it without the [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, add the dollar sign `\$` and escape the opening and closing parenthesis `\(` `\)` or else that would mean a capturing group.

[`(\$\w*->ShowMessage\(\))`](https://regex101.com/r/Cy3W3T/1)

If you are replacing the text and not referring to the the first capturing group you can omit the outer parenthesis.

**Find**

[`\$\w*->ShowMessage\(\)`](https://regex101.com/r/wTKE2Z/1)

**Replace**

`ShowMessage\(\)`